# Intl в JavaScript не обрабатывает 16-ричные числа!

Tags: javascript

Всем кайфа!
Форматирую числа при помощи Intl, нормально работает в двоичной, 8-ричной и десятичной системе. А вот 16-ричные числа возвращает NaN.

Задача! Сделать 16-ричное число в формате **. Т.е. цифра 2 должна быть 02

```js
const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat("en-US", {
    minimumIntegerDigits: 2,
});
console.log(`${ formatter.format( 9 ) }`) // 09
console.log(`${ formatter.format( 255..toString(2) ) }`) // 11,111,111
console.log(`${ formatter.format( 255..toString(8) ) }`) // 377
console.log(`${ formatter.format( 255..toString(16) ) }`) // NaN - т.е. не работает как надо, должно быть FF
```

Comment: Int'l работает с десятичными числами. То что он работает со некоторыми удачными строками это просто случайность. В общем не нужно пассатижами гвозди забивать

Comment: Но с большей частью справляется(2, 8, 10). И предназначен, как бы, форматировать числа. 
16 и 32 - ричные — это тоже числа. Значит, наверно, баг что: он не может!

Comment: Он их интерпретирует как десятичные